# Why I can't convert my text from UTF-8 to ASCII using iconv?

Tags: utf-8, ascii

I'm actually have a hard time trying to convert UTF-8 code to ASCII (I'm a beginner).

My input is a text file named text.txt with these words in utf-8 :

```
ÃŠtre
Ã‰loignÃ©e
Ã‰loignÃ©
Ã‰glise
```

So I used iconv to convert them to ASCII :

```
iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII texte.txt > text_ascii.txt
```

When using this command I have this error

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
```

So I checked the encoding of the file using

```
file -i  text.txt 
text.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

So here I am sure that the encoding it utf-8 but still it's not working ?

Does anyone know the solution for this please ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what the expected output would look like? I'm guessing some of these characters have no ASCII equivalent.

Comment: Also, please remove the 'C' tag. I don't see how this has any connection to the C programming language.

Comment: It should be Être  , éloignée , éloigné , église sorry for the C tag tought iconv was specific to c

Comment: Those accented characters cannot be represented in ASCII. You can use `-t ASCII//TRANSLIT` to make a best effort, but you're not going to really get what you want.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Éloignée'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `Ã‰loignÃ©e` and vice versa: `'Ã‰loignÃ©e'.encode('cp1252').decode()` -> `Éloignée`.

Comment: Here's an [amusing and informative](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) discussion about character encoding.